# idiomatic way to use suspend function and coroutineScope together to build dsl

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

We are building a dsl for our users to write domain scripts and we want to meet following expectation from such a scripts:

1. asynchronous and non blocking
2. default behavior should be sequential
3. should able to run tasks in parallel when needed

Our goal is to hide all the machinery from script writer.

- script writer should not see keywords like `coroutinescope`, `async`, `launch`.
- we have provided bunch of wrappers over suspend function as a part of our dsl for ex.

```scala
      // dsl
      fun handleCommand(f: suspend (Command) -> CommandResult)

      // usage from script
      handleCommand { cmd ->
        val event = getEvent() // suspending function
        // .....
      }
```

Here script writer does not need to worry about `async` and `non-blocking`, everything is abstracted out from them

- now we want a utility which runs `task` in `parallel`, to do this we have provided following `par` function

```scala
     // dsl
      suspend fun <T> par(block: () -> T): Deferred<T> = coroutineScope {
          async { block() }
      }

      // usage 
      handleCommand { cmd ->
        par { //task1  }
        par { //task2  }
        // call other suspending functions
      }
```

- As `par` is suspending function and takes a block of code and runs it in new coroutine, we can run as many tasks as we want in `parallel`
- As `par` is getting called from `handleCommand` (suspending function), all works fine and user does not need to deal with `coroutines` and family

So question is, signature of function `par`  ->  ***`suspend fun <T> par(block: () -> T): Deferred<T>`*** does not seem to be idiomatic and not as per general guidelines of using `suspend` vs `CoroutineScope` extensions.
Am I doing it correctly given above use cases/restrictions or is there a better way to achieve same?

Comment: Seems like you want to define a keyword to run a job asynchronously... have you considered `async`?

Comment: `par` internally spawns new `coroutine` using `async` but it does not require to be called from `coroutineScope` because it is getting called from `suspend` function
also `par { // ... }` this immediately starts executing in background

Comment: Your `par` call won't complete until the coroutine you started inside completes. You have to decouple specifying the block within which each line of code launches a background task from the function that actually launches the task. But, this is how it already is: `coroutineScope` is the former and `async` (or more appropriate to your use case, `launch`) is the latter.

Comment: On the other hand, if you want to get rid of the coroutine scope block, then you have chosen to work without structured concurrency. I don't recommend that.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, yes as you said in your first comment, it does not work the way I wanted it to. Above `par` implementation suspends from calling scope. I want it to run in background. 
Also as you mentioned in the seconds comment, `launch` or `async` does work as expected when used directly.
So lets assume my use case is that I want to rename `launch` or `async` to `par` keeping the behavior same, then how would I do that?

Comment: Following definition does work as I wanted -`fun <T> CoroutineScope.par(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T): Deferred<T> = async { block() }`